# Linq query :- Find records from nested list (array of objects)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have entity Program.

```
Class Program
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string ProgramName {get;set;}
   public List<Activity> Activities {get;set}
}
```

And Activity looks like :-

```
Class Activity
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Now I need to get all programs where activity `Id` = param `Id`.

This is what I tried
`var programs = _context.Program.Where(p => p.Activities.Select(a => a.Id).Contains(Id)).ToList();`

But it is giving error like

```
"The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Programs>\r\n    .Where(p => p.LocationId == __model_Tags_0 || p.Activity\r\n        .Select(a => a.Id)\r\n        .Contains(__model_Tags_0) && True)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().
```

Which is the better way(linq query) to solve this problem?

Comment: Could u provide some sample Data?

Comment: @TheTanic I don't have but the thing is to get all programs based on given activity Id. Ex. `Activity { id = 1, name = sample}`  we need to match Id = 1 and get all programs which have activity Id = 1

Comment: Your tags are contradictory. You need to specify: are you using LINQ to EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x? Also, what database provider / engine are you using?

Comment: Does it work if you put `Include(p => p.Activities)` before the `Where`?

Comment: @NetMage No because that's just a json. Not a separate entity .

Comment: So you are somehow mapping the JSON to `List<Activity>`? Then on the SQL side it is of type `JSON` or `varchar`? How would you expect EF to translate a query against the `List` to a query against `JSON`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Any` like `p.Activities.Any(a => a.Id == Id)` inside `Where` condition as below.

```
var programs = _context.Program.Where(p => p.Activities.Any(a => a.Id == Id)).ToList();
```

Comment: Same error even with `Any` ... `"The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Programs>\r\n    .Where(p => p.LocationId == __model_Tags_0 || p.Activity\r\n        .Any(a => a.Id == __model_Tags_0) && True)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated,`